# Regex match anything but a specific pattern

Tags: java, android, regex, match, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex, that matches anything but the pattern **\d+-\d+**

The to be ignored pattern is a number with one ore more digits followed by a hyphen then followed by another number with one or more digits.

For example:

*Test 123 Test* **123-123** *Test*

only "123-123" should not be matched

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `\\d+(?!-\\d+)`

Comment: do u want user to restrict - to type?

Comment: `s.split("\\d+-\\d+")`

Comment: why you don't use `"Test 123 Test 123-123 Test".replaceAll("\\d+-\\d+", "")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify if you want an expression for matching individual strings (`Pattern#matches(String, CharSequence)` or `String#matches(String)`) or if you want to find multiple matches in one string (`Matcher#find()`).

## Matching a Single String

The following branch is taken if `input` is *Test* or *123*, but not if it's *123-123*:

```
if (input.matches("(?s)(?!\\d+-\\d+).*")) {
    // ...
}
```

Although, if your code makes the actual `matches` call, you might as well write:

```
if (!input.matches("\\d+-\\d+")) {
    // ...
}
```

## Finding Matches in a String

If you want to find multiple matches in one string, much depends on how you want to tokenize. Here's example code that lists all whitespace-separated sequences that are **not** of the form `\d+-\d+`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^|\\s)(?!\\d+-\\d+)\\S+(?=$|\\s)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

For an input of "Test 123 Test 123-123 Test", the output would be:

```
Test
123
Test
Test
```

If you want to tokenize differently, you will have to adjust the boundary matching. Java's regular expressions have a word boundary matcher (`\b`), but *123-123* wouldn't be considered a word, because it contains a hyphen, which is not a regex word character.

Comment: I needed to find this pattern in a string. So the second part of your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much!